# Find m4b Files on Android Devices to play them in Exoplayer

Tags: java, android, audio, android-contentprovider, exoplayer

I would like to test Exoplayer to play m4b files.
As far as I have tested, m4b files are not recognised as audio files on Android devices.
I want to use the `contentProvider` to browse the device and find these files (and other audiofiles).

`MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC` does not result any of my m4b files.
If I use `MediaStore.Files`, then I have to enter the extension m4b as a filter. That's not what I want.

What is the best way, to find m4b files.

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: "That's not what I want" -- then what *do* you want? You could try searching for files with a MIME type of `audio/mp4a-latm`, but I do not know if Android recognizes that.

Comment: Thanks...Android doesn't know this mime type, so I'll get to the files via extension. Greetings, Alejandro